Strange Faces in high poly modeling
I have an issue. I'm working on a high-poly vantage calculator, and when I exit edit mode, a strange face appears in the model (). I've attached the  project file for your reference.{(google drive Project file link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PleFtDLcFW4DTV-BJGfuZIanJQxedyBR?usp=sharing )}

Multires modifier is not designed for such tasks. It is designed to make hi-res details while sculpting (but your mesh is bad for sculpting). If you make changes on the base, such artifacts are expected. Why don't you use Subdivision modifier instead?


Oh, that's right , thank you

@Bnn if the answer is correct, mark it as such   ;)
